# DOM override app

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm building a mini-app that will display when changes to the DOM have been made by JavaScript. I have all of the functions that I can think of listed in the code. Is there a way to consolidate the functions into one, and have the overrides still function correctly?

```
var DomChanges = (function() {

  var a = Element.prototype.appendChild
  , b = Element.prototype.removeChild
  , c = Element.prototype.insertBefore
  , d = Element.prototype.insertAfter
  , e = Element.prototype.insertAttribute
  , f = Element.prototype.removeAttribute
  , g = Element.prototype.replaceChild
  , h = Element.prototype.createElement;

  Element.prototype.appendChild = function(){
    DomChange('appendChild', arguments);
    a.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  Element.prototype.removeChild = function() {
    DomChange('removeChild', arguments);
    b.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  Element.prototype.insertBefore = function() {
    DomChange('insertBefore', arguments);
    c.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  Element.prototype.insertAfter = function() {
    DomChange('insertAfter', arguments);
    d.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  Element.prototype.insertAttribute = function() {
    DomChange('insertAttribute', arguments);
    e.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  Element.prototype.removeAttribute = function() {
    DomChange('removeAttribute', arguments);
    f.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  Element.prototype.replaceChild = function() {
    DomChange('replaceChild', arguments);
    g.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  Element.prototype.createElement = function() {
    DomChange('createElement', arguments);
    h.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  function DomChange (ftype, arguments) {
    console.log('Dom has been changed');
  };

}());
```

Comment: Are you unable to use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//
// maybe this:
//
"appendChild removeChild insertBefore insertAfter insertAttribute removeAttribute replaceChild createElement"
.split(" ")
.forEach(
    function ( ftype ) {
        var corefn = this[ftype]
        this[ftype] = function () {
            DomChange( ftype, arguments );
            return corefn.apply( this, arguments );
        };
    },
    Element.prototype
);
//
//  do you overide .innerHTML somehow?
//
```

Comment: It misses .innerHTML embeds, so you don't get notified when that occurs... Posible solution would be to run the timer fn on elements of interest checkig the state of the property, and running a callback when modification is spotted. I've posted the timer factory on SO here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544237/keep-calling-on-a-function-while-mouseover/18557620#18557620
), so you might consider using it if want to spot the mod.